# Running git-svn with cron results in garbage in .git

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git, cron

I've setup a git-svn repo with cron to fetch from the svn repo daily. I have a script to do the fetching, and this is what is invoked by cron. Everything is fine with the repo, and the script works fine when executed manually.

However, when it runs under cron, empty files get dropped into the .git directory. The files have names that look like they are some base64 output, e.g. juTrvjP6m8 and kcKf3hu3b4. Two of these files show up for every cron run. I thought these might be commit hashes, but they're not, git-show says it's an unknown revision.

I set-up the repo as follows:

```
git svn init http://svn.ip.addr/repo
git svn fetch svn-remote
```

My script looks like this:

```
cd /gitsvn/dir
git svn fetch svn-remote
git svn push pub
```

The last line pushes the repo to a separate (bare) public repo from which others can clone.

I'm piping the output from the cron job to a file, which looks like this:

```
fatal: unable to run 'git-svn'
Counting objects: 21, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 59.08 KiB, done.
Total 11 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
To /gitpub/repo.git
   360faf5..a153b0d  trunk -> trunk
```

The line "fatal: unable to run 'git-svn'" is alarming, but the fetch seems to go ahead anyway. Any suggestions? Where are these empty garbage files coming from, and how to stop them? Am I in for bigger problems in the future?

BTW, I'm using git 1.6.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing something is missing from the environment variables when git-svn is run from cron. Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780072/why-does-my-command-line-not-run-from-cron